# In Roslyn (Microsoft CodeAnalysis) how do I create a boolean literal?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn

Normally I would use the SyntaxFactory but I cannot figure out how to create a true or false node with it.

Comment: http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ may help here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just figured it out. true and false are keywords and I haven't had to deal with keywords much so I was looking in the wrong spot. Keywords apparently tend to rely on having their own SyntaxKind.

```
SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression( SyntaxKind.TrueLiteralExpression );
```

After searching for the last hour I finally remembered [this tool.](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) If anyone has a similar problem that tool might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to the Roslyn Quoter.